# Convert rating percent (50%) to the equivelant 5-star rating in PHP

Tags: php

I'm sure this is possible but my math isn't that fantastic.

I'm showing latest movies on my page and my application uses a 5-star rating system, however, the data I receive from a Web Service arrives as a percentage e.g. 50%.

Is there any way I can convert this percentage to a star rating equivalent, which in this case would be 50% = 2.5, allowing me to show 2.5 stars?

It seems fairly simple when I have 50% but if I get 94%, it confuses my poor little pea for a brain! Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to convert the `0..100` scale to a `0..5` scale, just divide by 20.

If you want it on a half-star boundary, then divide it by `10` instead and that's the number of half-stars you need.

Keep in mind I'm talking about *integer* division here, where the value is truncated (rounded down).

You may also want to consider rounding it more intelligently during the division, rather than truncating, so that something like 99% is 5 stars (not 4.5). This can be done by simply adding half the amount you're dividing by before the division, something like (in C):

```
int percent = 94;
int halfstars = (percent + 5) / 10;
```

This would give the following results for input values between 0 and 100 inclusive:

```
percent     halfstars
-------     ---------
  0-  4         0
  5- 14         1
 15- 24         2
 25- 34         3
 35- 44         4
 45- 54         5
 55- 64         6
 65- 74         7
 75- 84         8
 85- 94         9
 95-100        10
```

Comment: @paxdiablo: Indeed, 94% should be 4.5 stars.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That last sentence/code is really confusing. Taking 94% as the input it yields 9.9 half stars or 4.95 stars which is impossible and taking 99% as the input yields 10.4 half stars or 5.2 stars, which is also impossible. I think you should clarify that.

Comment: @Alix, it won't give 9.9 half stars since it's an _integer_ (truncating) division. Instead it will give 9, which translates to 4.5 stars. I'll clarify in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for finding the percentage of a number is fairly simple:

```
$percentInDecimalForm * $number
```

For example, a 94% rating would be:

```
.94 * 5 = 4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to solve the following:

```
100% ---------- 5
 94% ---------- x = (94 * 5) / 100 (=) x = 4.7
```

Now it's necessary to know the granularity of your star scale (how many times you can divide the star).

Since you mentioned 0.5 stars, I'm gonna assume your star granularity is 1 / 0.5 = 2, so just solve:

```
round(4.7 * 2) / 2 (=) 9 / 2 (=) 4.5
```